# How to discover embedded Jetty port after requesting random available port?

Tags: java, jetty

```
Server server = new Server(0);   
(..)
server.start();
// this returns _zero_ ?!?!
int listeningPort = server.getConnectors()[0].getPort();
```

I'm using embedded Jetty 7 API. Passing zero to the Server(int) constructor cause Jetty to assign an available port automatically, how can i discover which port was assigned?

I have read the docs, but cannot find this info.

thanks..

Comment: Found it! Use getLocalPort instead of getPort()!

Comment: This is a very useful technique for testing.

Answer (score 43):

The function `getPort()` returns the configured value.

Try `server.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort()` it should return the selected port.

For Jetty 9:

You need to use `((ServerConnector)server.getConnectors()[0]).getLocalPort()`.

In both cases: you need to call `server.start()` first.

Comment: Starting the server is important. If you try to get the port before the server is running, it will be returned as `-1`.

Comment: In my case, using Jetty embedded, I had to create and add a connector manually because otherwise I had no connector after calling `server.start()`. Here the Kotlin code:

`server.addConnector(ServerConnector(server).apply { port = 0 })`

Then I was able to use the technic suggested by @paskos to get the port.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [@pascos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14982831/2114786), you can also get the seleted port by:

```
server.getURI().getPort(); // e.g: 44759
```

If you are interested to get the whole server URL (with port), you can do:

```
server.getURI().toString(); // e.g: http://127.0.0.1:44759/
```